# Which 5 pages did she count the number of errors?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

An editor wishes to make a statement about the mean number of errors per page in a fifty page document. Since she does not want to look at every page, she decides that she will take a simple random sample of 5 pages, count the number of errors on each, calculate the mean number of errors per page on the sample 5 pages, and use it to estimate the number of errors per page in the entire document. To take the sample, she labels the pages with identifiers 01 through 50, and uses the sequence of random numbers below to select the sample. Based on this information, on which five pages did she count the number of errors?

Random Number Sequence:
1851, 9193, 8181, 0033, 0547, 6318, 2324, 8549, 6617

The answer is pages 18, 33, 05, 47, 23. 
I'm not sure how to start off in finding this answer, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very well-formulated problem, but seeing the answer is easy enough to figure out how it works.

It's not really a list of four-digit numbers, it's a list of two-digit numbers. It doesn't go $1851,9193,\ldots$, it goes $18,51,91,93,\ldots$. The editor has simply picked the first five valid page numbers on that list.

If she were to pick more pages, the next three would be, in order, $24,49$ and $17$.

Comment: Thank you very much! At first I couldn't figure out the answer of page 47, but now it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Split every number of $4$ digits in half, obtaining a sequence of numbers of $2$ digits.
Then we have page $01$ to $50$, so she only takes the numbers of $2$ digits between the range, discarding every page she already checked.